# value of select box is not retrieved using jquery in codeigniter

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

this is jquery code all the field names are accurate value of each element is retrieved except DistrictId, InstituteId and ComplainType. And these all are select box values

index file with jquery and html form, only the values of selece box is not retrieved

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("body").on('click', '#SaveComplain', function() {
    var date = new Date();
    var n = date.toDateString();
    var t = date.toLocaleTimeString();
    var time = n + ' ' + time;
    var FocalPerson = $('#FocalPerson').val();
    var Email = $('#Email').val();
    var ContactNumber = $('#ContactNumber').val();
    var InstituteId = $('#Institute').val();
    var ComplainDate = time;
    var ComplainStatus = 'Registered';
    var ComplaintDetails = $('#ComplaintDetails').val();
    var ComplaintType = $('#ComplaintType').val();
    var DistrictId = $('#District').val();

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'html',
      data: ('FocalPerson=' + FocalPerson + 'Email=' + Email + '&ContactNumber=' + ContactNumber + '&InstituteId=' + InstituteId + '&ComplainDate=' + ComplainDate + '&ComplainStatus=' + ComplainStatus + '&ComplaintDetails=' + ComplaintDetails + '&ComplaintType=' + ComplaintType + '&DistrictId=' + DistrictId),
      url: "<?php echo base_url('TicketSupport/SaveComplain'); ?>",
      redirect: true,
      success: function(response) {
        $('#msg').html('Complain Registered Successfully <br> Soon You will be Contacted by the Concerned Department');
      }
    });
  });

});

<div class="tab-content">
<div class="tab-pane active" id="formcontrols">
<form name="form" method="post" action="<?php echo 
base_url('TicketSupport/SaveComplain'); ?>" class="form-horizontal">
<fieldset>

<div class="control-group"> 
   <div class="controls">
      <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('record_added'); ?>
    </div> <!-- /controls -->               
 </div> <!-- /control-group -->

 <div class="control-group">                                         
       <label class="control-label" for="lastname">District:</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <select class="form-control span3" name="District" id="District" required="required">
   <option value="">Select District</option>
   <?php
   foreach ($AllDistricts as $AllDistrict) { 
   ?>
   <option value="<?php echo $AllDistrict['DistrictId']; ?>"> <?php echo $AllDistrict['DistrictName']; ?></option>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
  </select>
        </div> <!-- /controls -->               
    </div> <!-- /control-group -->


  <div class="control-group">                                         
        <label class="control-label" for="email">Institute:</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <div id="InstituteList">
        <select class="form-control span3" name="Institute" id="Institute" required="required">
            <option value="0">Select Institute </option>
        </select>
    </div>    
        </div> <!-- /controls -->               
    </div> <!-- /control-group -->

     <div class="control-group">                                         
        <label class="control-label" for="complaintype">Complain Type</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <select class="form-control span3" name="ComplaintType" id="ComplaintType" required="required">
            <option value="Finger Print Issue">Finger Print Issue</option>
            <option value="Device Problem"> Device Issue</option>
            <option value="Internet Connectivity Issue">Internet Connectivity Issue</option>
            <option value="Other"> Other</option>
            </select>
            <textarea id="other" class="form-control" name="ComplaintType" placeholder="Describe Issue" style="display: none;" rows="3"></textarea>
        </div> <!-- /controls -->               
    </div> <!-- /control-group -->

    <div class="control-group">                                         
        <label class="control-label" for="username">Name:</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" class="span3" id="FocalPerson" name="FocalPerson" required="required" placeholder="Enter Your Name">
        </div> <!-- /controls -->               
    </div> <!-- /control-group -->

    <div class="control-group">                                         
        <label class="control-label" for="username">Email:</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" class="span3" id="Email" name="Email" required="required" placeholder="Enter Your Email">
        </div> <!-- /controls -->               
    </div> <!-- /control-group -->


    <div class="control-group">                                         
        <label class="control-label" for="contactnumber">Contact Number:</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" class="span3" id="ContactNumber" name="ContactNumber" required="required" placeholder="Enter Contact Number">
        </div> <!-- /controls -->               
    </div> <!-- /control-group -->

    <div class="control-group">                                         
        <label class="control-label" for="complaindetails">Details</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <textarea class="form-control span6" rows="5" name="ComplaintDetails" id="ComplaintDetails" required="required"></textarea>
        </div> <!-- /controls -->               
    </div> <!-- /control-group -->

    <div class="form-actions">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" name="SaveComplain" id="SaveComplain">
        <input type="reset" class="btn" value="Reset" >
    </div> <!-- /form-actions -->
</fieldset>
```

that is my controller file

```
public function SaveComplain(){

    $Record = array(
   'FocalPerson' => $this->input->post('FocalPerson'),
   'Email' => $this->input->post('Email'),
   'ContactNumber' => $this->input->post('ContactNumber'),
   'InstituteId' => $this->input->post('InstituteId'),
   'ComplainDate' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
   'ComplainStatus' => 'Registered',
   'ComplainDetail' => $this->input->post('ComplaintDetails'),
   'ComplainType' => $this->input->post('ComplaintType'),
   'DistrictId' => $this->input->post('DistrictId'),
   );

    print_r($Record);
    die();
```

and that is result

```
Array ( [FocalPerson] => someone [Email] => someone@mail.com [ContactNumber] => 123456789 [InstituteId] => [ComplainDate] => 2017-12-21 07:08:24 [ComplainStatus] => Registered [ComplainDetail] => this is complain detail [ComplainType] => [DistrictId] => )
```

Comment: We need the html form also. And when you are using jQuery POST then send data in dtandered POST format like this:- `data: {'FocalPerson': FocalPerson ,'Email': Email, 'ContactNumber':ContactNumber,'InstituteId': InstituteId,'ComplainDate': ComplainDate,'ComplainStatus':ComplainStatus,'ComplaintDetails':ComplaintDetails,'ComplaintType':ComplaintType,'DistrictId':DistrictId},`

Comment: how can we use html form while we are using ajax-jquery

Comment: without any html how can he get values of `$('#FocalPerson').val();.... and so on`?

Comment: that's why i asked that we need to see html. because it seems there is problem in  `$('#District').val()` because of Html

Comment: index file as well